# tiny pyspark dataframe exploded in a huge one

Tags: python, pyspark

[image: Tiny datafrane]

My initial dataframe `df` is super tiny, it contains **10 000 000 rows** and fit into a single partition of **60Mb**.
The `repeat` column contains arrays of **sizes ranging from 1 to 10^9**.
I want to explode the `repeat` column like `df = df.select("*", F.explode("repeat"))` but it generates billions of records and I can't save it as a parquet file.
I tried to `repartition` before/after the `explode` but it does not work.

Comment: should filter the `None` value of the array in repeat first?

Comment: could you give a bit more detail as to what you are trying to do? Just running the numbers, you are trying to get from 10^7 rows to more than 10^16 which is quite a lot. What value do you have in repeat (I don't know if that's your screenshot but it looks like they are all either empty string or null). Is the goal to repeat each row 10^9 times?

Comment: have you tried splitting the repeat array into chunks (not sure which size will really make sense since it will depend on the data but you should experiment). So you would have an array of arrays `[[, , ,],...[, , ,]]` which you can then explode twice with a repartition in between the first and the second repartition.

Comment: @Seb, so the goal is to repeat the row times the size of the array in the column `repeat`. So if **row_1** has an array of size **10^9**, we want to duplicate the **row_1 10^9 times**. If **row_2**. has an array of size **2**, we want to duplicate the **row_2 twice**.

Comment: This post solved the issue:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52777421/python-spark-alternative-to-explode-for-very-large-data