# PySpark Mapping Elements in Array within a Dataframe to another Dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I have two dataframes. The first dataframe has an array as its value for `column2` and I want to join it with the second dataframe so the numerical values are mapped to their string values. The order of the elements should stay the same since they correspond to the array elements in `column3` by index.

`df_one`:

```
 column1|  column2|        column3
----------------------------------
"thing1"|[1,2,3..]|[0.1,0.2,0.3..]
"thing2"|[1,2,3..]|[0.1,0.2,0.3..]
"thing3"|[1,2,3..]|[0.1,0.2,0.3..]
...
```

`df_two`:

```
columnA|columnB
---------------
      1|"item1"
      2|"item2"
      3|"item3"
...
```

Is there a way to join these dataframes and select the columns like so:

```
column1 |                  newColumn|        column3
----------------------------------------------------
"thing1"|["item1","item2","item3"..]|[0.1,0.2,0.3..]
"thing2"|["item1","item2","item3"..]|[0.1,0.2,0.3..]
"thing3"|["item1","item2","item3"..]|[0.1,0.2,0.3..]
...
```

Comment: You could 'explode' df_one on 'column2', then join with df_two and use 'groupBy' on 'column1' on the resulting dataset with 'collect_list' to get it back as an array.

Comment: Would 'explode' be a good choice performance-wise? There are at least 1 million rows in df_one and each array in both columns have about 8k elements.

Comment: 'explode' does not add to the amount of data, it's the data shuffling that might impact your performance. see this post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52777421/python-spark-alternative-to-explode-for-very-large-data

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, `explode` on `column2` and then `join` on `columnA` is the good way to go. Yet, when you group back the data, I am not sure that the order would always be preserved.

To be sure, and avoid costly UDF in python, you could use `posexplode` to keep track of the position of each element, and then an ordered window function to build the list back:

```py
df_one = spark.createDataFrame([("thing1", [1, 2, 3], "X"), ("thing2", [1, 2, 3], "Y"), ("thing3", [1, 2, 3], "Z")],
                               ["column1", "column2", "column3"])
df_two = spark.createDataFrame([(1, "item1"), (2, "item2"), (3, "item3")],
                               ["columnA", "columnB"])

w = Window.partitionBy("column1").orderBy("pos")

df_one\
    .select("*", f.posexplode("column2").alias("pos", "columnA"))\
    .join(df_two, ['columnA'])\
    .withColumn("newColumn", f.collect_list("columnB").over(w))\
    .where(f.col("pos")+1 == f.size(f.col("column2")))\
    .select("column1", "newColumn", "column3")\
    .show(truncate=False)
```

```
+-------+---------------------+-------+
|column1|newColumn            |column3|
+-------+---------------------+-------+
|thing1 |[item1, item2, item3]|X      |
|thing2 |[item1, item2, item3]|Y      |
|thing3 |[item1, item2, item3]|Z      |
+-------+---------------------+-------+
```