# How to explode struct field in spark without explode command (Google Analytics)

Tags: pyspark, data-structures, apache-spark-sql, google-analytics, aws-glue

I need to run a query by spark, but I'm not getting it. I tried using the explode command, but the performance is very bad.

How can I browse the struct field by spark?

I would like to run totally on spark dataframe and I must run it in AWS Glue.

Thanks.

#standardSQL

```sql
SELECT
    visitNumber,
    visitId,
    fullVisitorId,
    hits.screenname,
    dim.value
FROM
    table,
    UNNEST(hits) AS hits,
    UNNEST(customDimensions) AS dim
LIMIT
    10;
```

I tried using the explode command, but the performance is very bad.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Can you please read [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) and edit your question to have better formatting (including code blocks for your code)? That makes it easier for reviewers and future readers to read your question :)

Comment: Does this help with your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/52803329/1477418

Comment: Thank you! I'm going to test it. By the way, how to put this answer as correct?

Comment: i think if it helps then you can upvote the other answer and mark this question as duplicate to the other question, or just add a modified solution as an answer to this question